# How to Make Use of 3 mm Filaments?

Tags: filament, extruder

I'm not really sure if I'm asking the right question here, but I just made a noob mistake of buying 3 mm filaments instead of 1.75 mm. I have a Makerbot Replicator 2 which I've been using and so far it is pulling in 1.75 mm quite well.

Is there any way I can still make use the 3 mm filaments, or do I need to use the filaments on different models? If it is the latter, which particular model is able to pull in 3 mm filament well?

Comment: Alvin, you will need to research. I know of no comparison site which lists printers based on filament diameter.

Comment: Thanks, Davo. So far, what I have learnt is that I need to mod the extruder and nozzle to be able to use the 3mm filaments.

Comment: Research also if modifying the extruder will void your warranty.

Comment: The extruder shouldn't need to be changed, I would have thought that just the hotend (and maybe the nozzle) would need to be changed.

Comment: The title you have chosen for your question is not very good. Asking for a list of printer models (or even just a recommendation for a single printer) does not make a good stack exchange question, because an answer would need to be unreasonably long, or would be opinion-based because we'd need to recommend one particular printer over all the others. Perhaps you can edit the title (and the body of the question) to focus on whether/how you can use 3mm filament in your printer and how you can tell whether a printer accepts 3mm filament.

Comment: Return the filament (or sell it) and buy the proper diameter. Save yourself a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a definitive answer (and has turned into a ramble), as I have not yet had to change my filament size.

However, initially, I would have thought that only the hotend and the hotend's nozzle would need to be changed, from one that can handle the 1.75 mm filament to 3 mm. If the extruder is spring loaded, then it should adjust itself to the thicker filament, without a problem. If not, then you may have to do a slight manual adjustment.

However, after doing some further reading, there may be other factors that need to be considered, such as:

- Extruder gearing;
- Melt time (which would imply a different feed rate)

It could be worth having a close look at the aperture of your hotend. If, in the unlikely situation, it looks as if the hotend would accept 3 mm (or if you could remove the lining so that it can), you *may* not need to actually change any hardware, but instead just try tweeking the **feedrate** in the software, because as your nozzle is less than the width of the filament anyway, then it will be fine for both 1.75 mm *and* 3 mm. A 3 mm filament would require more heating, and therefore a slower feedrate than a 1.75 mm feedrate. Once the filament has melted, so long as the pressure from the extruder is sufficient, then the molten filament should come out of the nozzle. However, this may be a less than satisafctory method and result in some dubious prints.

There is an interesting thread on the RepRap wiki, [1.75mm Filament vs 3mm Filament](http://forums.reprap.org/read.php?1,128719,page=1), that discusses most of the points above.

It should be noted that the advantages of 3 mm filament has over 1.75 mm are that it is:

- cheaper
- stiffer (less flexible) and thus "easier" to push through the hotend.

As an aside, one interesting point raised in the thread, is that maybe a smaller extruder can be used, for the narrower 1.75 mm filament, thus resulting in a lighter print head. I am not sure how true that is.

This article, [Converting a 3D printer from 3mm to 1.75mm](http://hackaday.com/2015/10/17/converting-a-3d-printer-from-3mm-to-1-75mm/), does the reverse of what you want, and comes with a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UcMw-3RizIw). It states that, as you have already found, that the hotend needs to be changed:

> The printer [Thomas] is changing out to accept 1.75mm is the Lulzbot
>   Mini, one of the most popular printers that would ever need this
>   modification. The only required materials is a new hot end suitable
>   for 1.75mm filament, a 4mm drill, and a few wrenches and allen keys.
>   It would be a smart idea to get a hot end that uses the same
>   thermistor as the old one, but that’s not a deal-breaker as the
>   problem can be fixed in the firmware.

Alternatively, you could leave your printer as it is and use a [3mm to 1.75mm filament converter](http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:72336), which may be a bit of overkill for just one reel of filament<sup>1</sup>.

#### The bottomline

To be honest, is it worth the hassle, time and expense of having to modify and re-calibrate your printer (or worst case, change the model of the printer), just for the price of a reel of filament (assuming that you did not bulk purchase a bunch of reels)? It may be better to stick to one filament size (i.e. your original size) for all of your projects, and so resell the reel of 3 mm and stick with the 1.75 mm printer and buy the correct filament<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> See also [Conversion of 3mm ABS filament to 1.75mm](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/38/conversion-of-3mm-abs-filament-to-1-75mm)

<sup>2</sup> See also [Tom's answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/38/conversion-of-3mm-abs-filament-to-1-75mm#answer-42) to [Conversion of 3mm ABS filament to 1.75mm](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/38/conversion-of-3mm-abs-filament-to-1-75mm)

See also [Can 1.75mm filament be used in a printer that takes 3mm filament?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/269/can-1-75mm-filament-be-used-in-a-printer-that-takes-3mm-filament)

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to actually write it like a literature review, even. I'll still need to experiment on it. I've actually upvote your answer nonetheless, but my reputation is too low to show an effect. I am looking into changing the hot end first. Wish me luck.

Comment: @AlvinHerawan - Not a problem, it was interesting for me too. Yes, you need 15 rep points to upvote. I've just given you 5. Remember to revisit this post when you have enough rep... Good luck! :-)

Comment: The extruder hobbel bolt (or whatever is used) is usually shaped round to better grip the filament. The radius of the teeth won't grip 3 mm filament at all, therefore it will likely skip or skid very easily, especially given the increased grip required for 3 mm filament. 1.75 <> 3 mm is a complete overhaul of anything related to the extrusion path. I did it.

Comment: @FarO - You should post that as an answer... it's useful info and should have more prominence than just a comment... I'll upvote it.

Comment: @Greenonline I think that was I found here on 3dp.SE back when I thought about the same!

Answer (score 2):

Well... Usually when one buys a 30 dollar roll of plastic they don't replace a 1k machine..

That said you can change out the extruder. The extruder is what matters. So if you have a Prusa i3, you can go and buy say a e3d hot end that is made for 3mm.

Usually we see 3mm on Bowden printers like the Ultimaker. Everyone else has moved to 1.8.

I would just toss this on craigslist and get the correct plastic.

Comment: Yeah, agree with you ... I was just curious with this 3mm size. Of course I'd rather toss the whole spool ... perhaps find a use for it somehow, someday.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party here but I am doing this exact thing. I stupidly bought like a dozen rolls of 3mm filament for about $6 a Kg. I think trying the switch should be fun...but I have 7 printers so its no big deal to tinker on one of them.

What you need to do is modify the extruder. I have done this successfully using the crappy plastic extruders which come with most budget printers. You have to drill out the filament path to fit the 3 mm filament. It does get a little tricky to get the filament to run through nicely.

You actually **do not** need to modify your hot end other than your Bowden tube and your nozzle. Regular Bowden tube is 2 mm ID and 4 mm OD, so you just order 3 mm ID and 4 mm OD tube. Please note that this plan **will not** work for an all metal 1.75 mm hotend.

For the nozzle you can often find 3 mm compatible nozzles. Unfortunately they don't seem to be made for the MK10 hotend. So I simply ordered big ole 1 mm nozzles made for 1.75 mm and I am going to drill out the back for the 2.85 mm (3 mm) filament.

I am excited to see how this all works. You can get some really good deals on 3 mm filament *and* I suspect that it will actually work much better for things like TPU since it is significantly more rigid due to the increased diameter!

Answer (score 0):

Any modern and decent drive gear (single or dual) is shaped round (concave) to better grip the filament.

[image]

Some are flat, but only the cheapest and least performing ones.

[image]

(from [Reprap wiki](https://reprap.org/wiki/Drive-gear))

The concave part designed for 1.75 mm filament will be too small to accept 3 mm filament, it will grip it so weakly that it will skip or skid very easily, especially given the increased grip required for 3 mm filament.

1.75 <-> 3 mm is a complete overhaul of anything related to the extrusion path. I did it so I know...